# Angular MonoRepo Secondary Enpoints with different paths

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have a monorep using **@nx** and **@angular** and I have setup a folder structure as follows:

```
libs
- ui-components
--_components
---atoms
----alert
---molecules
----datepicker
--alert
--datepicker
```

As you can see, all folders and files reside in the ui-components folder.
In my `tsconfig.base.json` I have setup secondary endpoints for the library root components as follows:

```
"@library-name/ui-components/alert": ["libs/ui-components/alert/index.ts"],
"@library-name/ui-components/datepicker": ["libs/ui-components/datepicker/index.ts"],
```

and in those root folders I just have an `index.ts` and a `ng-package.json`.
The `index.ts` is pointing to the `_components` folder at the respective component like this:

```
export * from '../_components/atoms/alert';
```

If I run my project or storybook, it works fine. But if I try to build the project, I get this error:

> /_components/atoms/alert/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '

I have tried many ways to solve this.
One way was to add a `ng-package.json` to the actual component (in `/_components/atoms/alert/`) and then change the `<rootDir>/alert/index.ts` to this:

```
export * from '@library-name/ui-components/_components/atoms/alert';
```

While this does work, it causes the built library to have 2 endpoints, 1 in root and 1 in the _components directory. This might not seem like an issue, but GitLab has a character count limit for package.json and having duplicates puts us over that limit.

So, I need to solve this without using secondary entries.
Anyone have any ideas?

---

https://github.com/r3plica/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx

If you build that project, you will see this in package.json (for the ui-components library)

```
{
  "name": "@angular-storybook-tailwind-nx/ui-components",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "sideEffects": false,
  "module": "esm2022/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components.mjs",
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": {
      "default": "./package.json"
    },
    ".": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components.mjs"
    },
    "./badge": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-badge.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-badge.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-badge.mjs"
    },
    "./button": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-button.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-button.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-button.mjs"
    },
    "./header": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-header.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-header.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-header.mjs"
    },
    "./layout": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-layout.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-layout.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-layout.mjs"
    },
    "./_components/atoms/badge": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-badge.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-badge.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/badge/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-badge.mjs"
    },
    "./_components/atoms/button": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-button.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-button.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/_components/atoms/button/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-atoms-button.mjs"
    },
    "./_components/templates/header": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/_components/templates/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-header.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/_components/templates/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-header.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/_components/templates/header/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-header.mjs"
    },
    "./_components/templates/layout": {
      "esm2022": "./esm2022/_components/templates/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-layout.mjs",
      "esm": "./esm2022/_components/templates/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-layout.mjs",
      "default": "./esm2022/_components/templates/layout/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx-ui-components-_components-templates-layout.mjs"
    }
  }
}
```

Note the double endpoints for each component. I don't want the "internal" endpoints (any that have the _components directly in them)

Comment: You can modify your folder structure to better align with the Angular and Nx best practices. One common approach is to place each library as a separate Nx library within the libs directory. This approach will make it easier to manage and build your libraries without the need for additional configuration.

Comment: NX has a command to [generate entrypoints](https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/generators/library-secondary-entry-point) in a library. Without more code it's hard to judge what's wrong with your setup. Perhaps your [`ng-package.json`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/modal/ng-package.json) is wrong? It seems that the files are NOT in the src folder, which is okay. But I had to keep something under my main entrypoint (=src folder) for the project to compile...

Comment: https://github.com/r3plica/angular-storybook-tailwind-nx you can see the test project I made here

Comment: You don't need to define the `"exports"` field in the `package.json` yourself, including the `./package.json`. Remove that.  Ng-packagr does that for you. The only thing you can keep is the package.json exports are scss files and other resources.

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) an example of an angular component library with sub-entrypoints